# How to print the cycle contains node in a directed graph in C++

Tags: c++, graph, cycle

I am writing a program that will detect cycle in a directed graph and will print the nodes that built the cycle. I try use to use a recursive method using C++ by not understanding how to print these nodes after a cycle is detect. Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void addedge(list<int>,int ,int );
void cycle_check(list<int>*,int);

//  Make a pair between vertex x and vertex y
void addedge(list<int> *ls,int x,int y){
ls[x].push_back(y);
return;
} 

void check_cycle_util(list<int> *ls,bool *visit,int curr_node,int &temp){
visit[curr_node]=true;
list<int>::iterator it;
for(it=ls[curr_node].begin();it!=ls[curr_node].end();it++){
    if(!visit[*it]){
        check_cycle_util(ls,visit,*it,temp);
    }
    else{
        if(temp==0){
            temp=1;
            cout<<"There is a cycle in the graph\n";
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
//checking the cycles in a graph 
void cycle_check(list<int>*ls,int num){
bool *visit=new bool[num];
int temp=0;
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    visit[i]=false;
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    if(!visit[i] && temp==0){
        check_cycle_util(ls,visit,i,temp);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
int num;
cout<<"Enter the no. of vertices :";
cin>>num;
list<int> *ls=new list<int>[num];
addedge(ls,0,1);
addedge(ls,2,3);
addedge(ls,3,4);
addedge(ls,4,5);
addedge(ls,1,2);
addedge(ls,1,4);
addedge(ls,3,0);
cycle_check(ls,6);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could learn the Tarjan Shrink Point Algorithm, it's used to search the strongly connected components.

The main idea is using the same value to mark all the points of a strongly connected component. So the points have the same value are in the same cycle.

The main steps are these:

1. First, we define two arrays for points, one is the timestamp array, it means the sequence number in the DFS. The other is the low stamp array, it means the min value of the timestamp of the point through DFS, in other words, the value of one point is the min value among timestamp of the point itself and the low stamps of the linked points.
2. Use DFS to assign the low stamp array, and then all the points which have the same low stamp are in the same cycle.

P.s: Because my Engish is not good so that I can't explain the algorithm very clear. So I recommend you could see another article to learn about this algorithm.

This is an example for using the stack to save path:

the path is a vector defined as a global variable

```cpp
visit[curr_node]=true;
path.push_back(curr_node);
/* other code */
if(temp==0){
            temp=1;
            cout<<"There is a cycle in the graph\n";
            break;
            for(auto i=path.size()-1;path[i]!=curr_node||i==path.size();--i){
                 cout<<path[i];
            }
  }
}
path.pop_back();
```

Comment: Sorry, I ignore the case that two or more cycle has the same point, the algorithm could not solve this case.

Comment: And then I have another idea that you can use a stack to save the path and when you find the cycle, pop the elements until poping the visited point.

Comment: can you further describe this, maybe a short sudo code or alogorithm

Comment: @MahmudulHasanSuzan I append the code at the end of my answer, the code is based on your code of the function "check_cycle_util"

Answer (score 0):

You can check out `Algorithms FOURTH EDITION by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne` and search for the section `Finding a directed cycle`, which gives the full java code and diagrams.
Modifying it to c++ is very simple

```cpp
class DirectedCycle
{
  vector<vector<int>> graph;  //index:node i,vec: The next node of this node
  vector<bool> visited;
  vector<int> edgeTo;//edgeTo[v]=w means w->v,Being used for backtracking paths
  vector<int> cycle; //store cycle path
  vector<bool> onStack;//All vertices on the stack during dfs
public:
  DirectedCycle(vector<vector<int>> g, int n)
  {
    graph = g;
    visited.resize(n);
    edgeTo.resize(n);
    onStack.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) DFS(i);
  }
  void DFS(int v)
  {
    visited[v] = true;
    onStack[v] = true;//add to stack
    for (auto item : graph[v])
    {
      if (HasCycle()) return;
      if (!visited[item])
      {
        edgeTo[item] = v;
        DFS(item);
      }
      else if (onStack[item])
      {
        cycle = vector<int>();
        for (int x = v; x != item; x = edgeTo[x])
          cycle.push_back(x);
        cycle.push_back(item);
      }
    }
    onStack[v] = false;//remove from the stack
  }
  bool HasCycle()
  {
    return !cycle.empty();
  }
  vector<int> CyclePath()
  {
    return cycle;
  }
};
```