# Print all cycles in a directed graph

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix for a graph. And I need to output all the cycles in this graph. How can I do this using dfs?

```
void al_dfs(int tmp_vertex,int** Graph,vector<int>& color,int number,vector<int>& result){
    color[tmp_vertex] = 1;
    for(int i = 0;i<number;i++){
        if((color[i] == 0)){ al_dfs(i,Graph,color,number,result); result.push_back(i); };
        if((color[i] == 1)){
            for(int i = 0;i< result.size();i++) cout << result[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    color[tmp_vertex] = 2;
}
```

I wrote a small function, but I understand that there is a lot of things that have not been completed yet.

Comment: Are you looking for algorithmic help or do you know how you think about it and have a specific problem coding it?    I don't understand why you're setting the color to `2`, for example

Comment: @lucidbrot I'm looking for algorithmic help.2 means the vertex is processed.

Comment: Maybe anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-a-directed-graph#comment2892719_546655) is helpful to you? The second-highest voted answer there does not seem to me like it does what you stated. What exactly are your requiements? Just detecting whether there is at least one circle is way easier than *printing* *all* circles. And do you specifically want to do this "using bfs"?

Comment: Why are you passing Graph as parameter? You're not using it. Try to be more complete. It's rather difficult to help you with so little info.

Answer (score 0):

You can reading `<Algorithms FOURTH EDITION by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne>` and search for the section `Finding a directed cycle`, which gives the full java code and diagrams.

```cpp
class DirectedCycle
{
  vector<vector<int>> graph;  //index:node i,vec: The next node of this node
  vector<bool> visited;
  vector<int> edgeTo;//edgeTo[v]=w means w->v,Being used for backtracking paths
  vector<int> cycle; //store cycle path
  vector<vector<int>> cycles;
  vector<bool> onStack;//All vertices on the stack during dfs
public:
  DirectedCycle(vector<vector<int>> g, int n)
  {
    graph = g;
    visited.resize(n);
    edgeTo.resize(n);
    onStack.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) DFS(i);
  }
  void DFS(int v)
  {
    visited[v] = true;
    onStack[v] = true;//add to stack
    for (auto item : graph[v])
    {
      if (HasCycle()) return;
      if (!visited[item])
      {
        edgeTo[item] = v;
        DFS(item);
      }
      else if (onStack[item])
      {
        cycle = vector<int>();
        for (int x = v; x != item; x = edgeTo[x])
          cycle.push_back(x);
        cycle.push_back(item);
        cycles.push_back(cycle);
        cycle.clear();
      }
    }
    onStack[v] = false;//remove from the stack
  }
  bool HasCycle()
  {
    return !cycle.empty();
  }
  vector<vector<int>> CyclePath()
  {
    return cycles;
  }
};
```

Comment: Finding *a* cycle is way easier than finding *all* cycles.

Comment: Following the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963922/how-to-print-the-cycle-contains-node-in-a-directed-graph-in-c/77216580#77216580), you only need to save a cycle into a two-dimensional array when you find it.

Comment: There are O(2^n) cycles in a graph with n edges. DFS has O(n) complexity so it cannot find all cycles in principle.